# Removing :hover on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css, hover, cross-browser

I appreciate there are answers to this question but I have yet to find a solution that works for me.

I have a dropdown menu that has styles applied upon `:hover`, in mobile viewports this shouldn't be applicable for obvious reasons.

The dropdown is structured something like:

```
<div className={ styles.dropdownWrapper }>
        <span className={ styles.dropdownLabel }>{ label }</span>
        <object className={ styles.dropdownArrow }></object>
        <div className={ styles.dropdownOptions }>
            <div className={ styles.dropdownItem }>
                <span>Settings</span>
            </div>
            <div className={ styles.dropdownItem }>
                <span onClick={ () => console.log("logout") }>Logout</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

With styling:

```
.dropdownWrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdownOptions {
  display: none;
}

.dropdownItem {
  padding: 0.4em;
}

.dropdownItem hr {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #979797;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdownWrapper:hover .dropdownOptions {
  top: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  background-color: #36394f;
  border-radius: 2px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.dropdownArrow {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: inline("./downArrow.svg");
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .dropdownOptions {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }

  .dropdownArrow, .dropdownHr {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

The above code functions as it should in Firefox desktop and mobile, Chrome desktop but not mobile. The problem is that the `onClick()` is not fired because the `:hover` appears to be retained and is causing the dropdown items to be "hidden".

I previously found this [solution](https://gist.github.com/perjo927/e1f114398fc6fb8538a1412bea800f1a) but this is now depreciated in Firefox desktop.

My next solution was to update the css as follows:

```
@media (hover: hover) {
  .dropdownWrapper:hover .dropdownOptions {
    top: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1em 1em 0.5em 1em;
    background-color: #36394f;
    border-radius: 2px;
    min-width: 100px;
  }
}
```

Which fixes the Chrome mobile issue but does not work in Firefox desktop.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a mobile-first strategy. It consists in applying CSS rules to mobile devices, and overwrite them (or add some) for larger screens.

**This way**, you should define your CSS rules for mobile devices, **then** use a media query to target larger screens

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) { 
 .dropdownWrapper:hover .dropdownOptions {
  top: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  background-color: #36394f;
  border-radius: 2px;
  min-width: 100px;
 }
}
```

Try add this code :)